# How to use jQuery to Overlay HTML elements?

Tags: jquery

Can somebody suggest a jQuery solution how i can make the #overlay slideDown() over the top of my #header when the #trigger button is clicked?

My goal is obviously have the overlay element slide down nicely on top of my header section covering it completely once the button is clicked.

Have a look at my code below.

http://codepen.io/ELiHimself/pen/EjQMmp

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>This is the header.</h1>
</div>

<div id="overlay">
  <h1>This is the overlay.</h1>
</div>

<button id="trigger">Trigger</button>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

#header h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

#overlay {
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

#overlay h1 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#overlay").hide();

  $("#trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").slideDown(700);
  });  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  //also add this lines to make sure the overlay covers everything you have in the header
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `#overlay` display on none;

```
#overlay {
  display: none;
  background-color: green;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And the query can be like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block").slideToggle(700);//Or goes UP or goes DOWN
  });
});
</script>
```

Or if you realy only want that it goes down then do this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#trigger").on("click", function() {
    $("#overlay").css("display", "block").slideDown(700);
  });
});
</script>
```

[EDIT]

Easy, move the `<div id="overlay">` above the `<div id="header">`

Comment: Nop. That makes the overlay show up directly below my header NOT on top of it which is what i am after. What i have in my initial example is the same result like what you did with "display: none".

Comment: What do you want then exactly?

Comment: When you click the trigger button, i want the overlay to slide down over the top of the header. So the header is below the overlay is directly on top of it.